# Djangosphinx failed to read searchd response

Tags: django, sphinx, django-sphinx

The error is djangosphinx.models.SearchError: failed to read searchd response
(status=2613, ver=11825, len=775174445, read=75)

Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
root@haoran-Lenovo:~/wiscode/apps/question# python try.py
<SphinxQuerySet instance>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 84, in <module>
    print results[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_sphinx-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/djangosphinx/models.py", line 266, in __getitem__
    return self._get_data()[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_sphinx-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/djangosphinx/models.py", line 400, in _get_data
    self._result_cache = list(self._get_results())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_sphinx-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/djangosphinx/models.py", line 526, in _get_results
    results = self._get_sphinx_results()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_sphinx-2.1.4-py2.6.egg/djangosphinx/models.py", line 513, in _get_sphinx_results
    raise SearchError, client.GetLastError()
djangosphinx.models.SearchError: failed to read searchd response (status=2613, ver=11825, len=775174445, read=75)
```